# Error while converting mp4 to ogg /usr/bin/ffmpeg: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

```
sudo ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i /home/alfanso/work/project/public/slides/file.mp4 -strict -2 -acodec vorbis -b:v 10k /home/alfanso/work/project/public/slides/file.ogg
```

I get following error

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 26 2014 18:52:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:1.2.6-1~trusty1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    53.  5.103 / 53.  5.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/alfanso/work/xmedica/public/slides/SSO_Test708888fdd0f788475e42a74ee39a54b1318fb9ad.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
  Duration: 00:00:22.27, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 801 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1600x896 [SAR 1:1 DAR 25:14], 721 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 75 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[NULL @ 0x2596a00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'
/usr/bin/ffmpeg: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the binary name twice. Simple remove the `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`:

```
sudo ffmpeg -y -i /home/alfanso/work/project/public/slides/file.mp4 -strict -2 -acodec vorbis -b:v 10k /home/alfanso/work/project/public/slides/file.ogg
```

The first `ffmpeg` already is the name of the program you want to run. The second one was passed as an argument to `ffmpeg` (so the program `ffmpeg` was started, and its first argument was set to `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`).

Comment: Still getting same error 

`Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height`



It also has one warning 



`Current FFmpeg Vorbis encoder only supports 2 channels.`

Comment: That's not the same error at all?! Your new error is telling you that the Vorbis encoder only supports audio with 2 channels, but your input file only has a mono audio stream. You need to [convert the mono channel to stereo](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation), using `-ac 2`.

Comment: Yup, that worked.. Actually i don't know anything what mono audio stream means.. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Mono and Stereo? Mono audio means there is only one audio channel. Stereo means there are two, one for the left side (ear) and another one for the right side (ear). Your source only has one audio stream and thus is mono. By converting this one stream to two streams, both sides actually play the same audio information.

Comment: `libvorbis` should always be used instead of the experimental `vorbis` and probably doesn't have this channel limitation.